# Setting up a .NET 4.5 application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I have an application built using .NET version 4.5

I created a site in IIS and pointed it to my application, but I'm receiving this error:

> The 'targetFramework' attribute in the  element of the Web.config file is used only to target version 4.0 and later of the .NET Framework (for example, ''). The 'targetFramework' attribute currently references a version that is later than the installed version of the .NET Framework. Specify a valid target version of the .NET Framework, or install the required version of the .NET Framework.

This applications works correctly if I'm running it on my local machine, but for some reason I can't get it to run with IIS.

Comment: is your apppool set to run 4.0?

Comment: Are you getting this error on a server, or from IIS on your local machine?

Comment: @DanielA.White - yes it is

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - it's on a separate server

Comment: And is the 4.5 framework installed on that server?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy - oops, no it wasn't. That fixed the issue.

Comment: I get the same error but 4.5.1 *is* installed on server.  If I run the code snippet from this page to check if 4.5 or greater installed, it returns true.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx  So I'm kind of stuck as well.

Comment: I was wrongly informed about installed version.  Using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx I see that I only had 4.5.  Off to install 4.5.1 and test.

Answer (score 1):

Select the correct application pool...

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731755(v=ws.10).aspx